# R connection problem the DB(sqlite) The LabDB is provided with data change the current working directory of R,when query applied error comes

Tags: r, sqlite, package, connection

```
 getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Alish Chelackal/Documents"
 setwd("C:/Users/Alish Chelackal/Desktop/data base/project/task3")

 library(RSQLite)
 database <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname='TheLabDB')

 dbDisconnect(database)
 database <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname='TheLabDB')


 statement <- "SELECT * FROM benches;"
 result <- dbSendQuery(database,statement)
```

> Error: no such table: benches

```
 rows <- dbFetch(result, n=10)
```

> Error in dbFetch(result, n = 10) : object 'result' not found

Comment: If the table isn't present, there's nothing we can do. Try `DBI::dbListTables(database)` to see if perhaps it's a spelling typo or something similar. Another thought is that the filename is different. Does it have a filename extension? Normally (in my experience) it has either `.db` or `.sqlite` or `.sqlite3` as an extension. Windows hinders this by hiding (never a good thing) extensions for known file types (they should always be shown, for security and issues like this). Try `file.exists("TheLabDB")` (likely false) and `Sys.glob("TheLabDB*")`.

Comment: (For my suggestion to enable extensions, see https://superuser.com/q/494312/402193)

Answer (score 0):

If sqlite3 does not find the named database, it creates a new (empty) database (in current working directory). You can use full path here `dbname="/path_to_db/TheLabDB"` or change the order of execution so the `setwd` executes *after* the `dbConnect`.